# Delphi: Win key allowed in shortcuts?

Tags: delphi

Can I set somehow for TMainManu items shortcuts with WIN key? E.g. set "Win+Alt+S". Does TShortcut type support WIN key. I use Delphi 7.

Comment: It's surely possible to do this. However you should not do so. Shortcuts involving the Windows key are reserved for use by the system. If you insist on implementing such a shortcut, do make sure that you pay special attention to your application's uninstaller. It's sure to get a lot of use.

Comment: Not bad to ALLOW users to enter (via settings) such shortcut. It's sure to get a lot of new keys for user. I have lot of keys busy already

Comment: It most certainly is bad. You should not do it.

Comment: No, Win logo key won't work as **accelerator key** in VCL, you cannot use it as modifier in `TShortCut` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using `TShortCut`, with either the menu designer or in code. Dropping a `TMainMenu` on a form, adding a `TMenuItem`, and trying to assign the <kbd>Win</kbd> raises an "invalid property value" exception, and it doesn't work when trying to do so with `KeyToShortCut` in code either.

The only modifiers you should use for shortcuts are <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, according to Microsoft. The <kbd>Win</kbd> key belongs to Windows. That's why it has that name :-)

Comment: How do you explain OneNote's `Win+S` shortcut?

Comment: @Andreas: I'm guessing that it's because they're not following the rules that MS established. :-) I'll rephrase from "can" to "should, according to MS".

Comment: The fact that you should not do this in no way means that it cannot be done.

Comment: You said that it *should* not be done. I don't see anything that says that it *cannot* be done with TShortcut.

Comment: @David: It's very easy to test (which I did). Drop a TMainMenu on the form, add an item, and try to use it's ShortCut property to assign the Win key as a modifier. It's not there, and can't be entered ("invalid property value" exception). Try to do it in code using `KeyToShortCut`. It doesn't work.

Comment: @KenWhite Indeed. This I already know. I'm trying to make the point that you did not anywhere state that. You did not state that it's not possible to do this with `ShortCut`. Instead you said that MS guidelines advise that you *should* not do so. I see nothing in your answer specific to the VCL and its `ShortCut` handling. I'm going to repeat my comment above. You said that it *should* not be done. I don't see anything that says that it *cannot* be done with `TShortcut`.

Comment: @David, got it. I was reading your suggestion differently. Good advice; I've edited to try and make what I was trying to say more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot respond to such a shortcut from the `ShortCut` property of a VCL control, at least so far as I can tell. Delphi's shortcut mechanism won't treat the Windows key as a modifier. Therefore you would need to include it as a non-modifier key. But a Delphi shortcut can only refer to a single non-modifier key, and you'd need two non-modifiers for your key press.

However, you can add your own bespoke handling and respond to such a key press. For example in the `OnShortCut` event of your form. This is very crude, but illustrates that it is possible.

```
procedure TMyForm.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (GetKeyState(VK_LWIN)<0) and (GetKeyState(VK_MENU)<0) then begin
    if Msg.CharCode = ord('S') then begin
      // do something
      Handled := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now, I'm not going to attempt to tidy this up, or do it properly, since the guidelines are very clear that you should not respond to shortcuts involving the Windows key. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) says:

> Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system.

I just wanted to prove that it is perfectly possible to handle such key presses in your application.

Comment: You're correct. :-) I missed it. I saw the code, and skimmed the text too fast. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN, however, use the windows key as part of global hotkeys.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx
So you COULD make it seem like it was acting as a shortcut, but in fact, would be system-wide.  So you SHOULD not do it.

Comment: You should not use WIN key in a global hot key either. It should not be used by anyone other than the system period.

Comment: @David: So you don't approve of OneNote's `Win+S` shortcut?

Comment: MS does not approve of it. It says: *Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system.*

Comment: @David: OK (You know that OneNote is a Microsoft product?) This isn't the first time Microsoft contradicts itself, though.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I do know that. I expect that the OS division people are just as pissed at the Office team as they would be at any other developer.